# Pass property reference from one class to another

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Say I've got 2 classes `Auth` and `Client`. If I have a property `Auth.token` I would like to be able to pass that property to `Client.token` as a reference so that when I change `Auth.token` it also changes the value of `Client.token`.

Here's an simplified example that currently doesn't work..

```
class Auth {
  constructor() {
    this._token = '123';
  }
  get token() {
    return this._token;
  }
  updateToken(newToken) {
    this._token = newToken;
  }
}

class Client {
  constructor(token) {
    this._token = token;
  }
  fetch() {
    console.log(this._token);
  }
}

const auth = new Auth();
const client = new Client(auth.token);
client.fetch();
auth.updateToken('abc');
client.fetch();
```

Comment: Maybe an event emitter like this might work https://github.com/Olical/EventEmitter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could pass your `Auth` instance to your `Client` instance and access `token` through `Auth`. This would ensure that updates to the `Auth._token` would effect the `Client`:

```js
class Auth {
  constructor() {
    this._token = '123';
  }
  get token() {
    return this._token;
  }
  updateToken(newToken) {
    this._token = newToken;
  }
}

class Client {
  constructor(auth) {
    this._auth = auth;
  }
  fetch() {
    console.log(this._auth.token);
  }
}

const auth = new Auth();
const client = new Client(auth);
client.fetch();
auth.updateToken('abc');
client.fetch();
```

Comment: Some interesting answers but I like this the best. It's simple and means I don't have to have a global. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Making a global variable would be one way of achieving this. You can then simply update the token via the `Auth`.

```js
let token = ''

class Auth {
  constructor() {
    token = '123';
  }
  get token() {
    return token;
  }
  updateToken(newToken) {
    token = newToken;
  }
}

class Client {
  fetch() {
    console.log(token);
  }
}

const auth = new Auth();
const client = new Client();
client.fetch();
auth.updateToken('abc');
client.fetch();
```